# Ad-hoc queries to a massive JSON dataset

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, apache-drill

I have a massive dataset stored in Azure BLOB in JSON format. Some apps are constantly adding new data to it. BLOBs are organized in partitions like

```
/dataset={name}/date={YYYY-MM-DD}/one_or_more_json_files
```

Data pieces do not follow any particular schema. JSON field names are not in consistent letter case. Some JSON rows can be broken.

Could someone advise a good way to query this data without defining schema in advance. I would like to do something like

```sql
select * from my_huge_json_dataset where dataset='mydataset' and date>'2015-04-01'
```

without defining explicit schema for the table

My first consideration was HIVE but it turns out that SerDe needs schema to be defined to create a table. json_tuple could be an answer but it is case-sensitive  and crashes if meets malformed json row.

I am also considering Apache Drill and Pig but have no experience with them and would like some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Apache Drill, you only need to configure a new storage pointing to your dataset folder:

```
 {
  "type": "file",
  "enabled": true,
  "connection": "file:///",
  "config": null,
  "workspaces": {
    "root": {
      "location": "/",
      "writable": false,
      "defaultInputFormat": null
    },
    "tmp": {
      "location": "/tmp",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null
    }
  },
"formats": {
 "json": {
      "type": "json",
      "extensions": [
        "json"
      ]
    }
}
```

So, if you defined that Storage Plugin as 'dfs' for example you could query from the root directory without defining any schema using ANSI SQL, just like:

```
SELECT * FROM dfs.dataset.date.`file.json`;
```

or even filter by your folder name in the same query using `dir0`.

I encourage you to visit their documentation site  [Apache Drill documentation](http://drill.apache.org/docs/) in your case specially [Querying JSON files](http://drill.apache.org/docs/querying-json-files/)

Comment: Does it support partitioning or queries to only single file?

Comment: @Ruslan yes you can query a single file or a directory (assuming all the files having a very similar json structure) and you can also optimize querys by partitioning data [see this example](https://drill.apache.org/docs/how-to-partition-data/)